# Delphi 5 calling C++ dll causing Access Violation

Tags: delphi, c++-cli

Here is the Delphi code calling the C++/CLI DLL:

```
implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure CallMe(x: Integer); stdcall; external 'CppWrapper.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  CallMe(1); 
end;

end.
```

After clicking the form button I get an exception.

Comment: Yes, please provide the C++ code - at the very least, the function declaration. I strongly suspect calling convention mismatch.

Comment: That was it... Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you! Please change to answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your C++ function is declared as `__stdcall`.

Comment: My psychic-debugging said, "Calling convention"